# How to set State in component did mount just after dispatching an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my component I have dispatched an action just after component mounts. Here the problem is when action is dispatched it gets data from server and I want to add those data to local State. But if I put `setState` in component like this is does not works.
Here `getParams` get value from url if there is available value.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const getParam = this.getParamsValue();
    const year = getParam.year ? getParam.year : 2020;
    this.props.getFilterData(year);   // <-- here this is the dispatch functions.
  
    if (this.props.dispensingData.loading) {  // <-- this is coming from redux state.
        this.setState({
            selectTab: getParam.tab ? parseInt(getParam.tab) : 0,
            dataTo: getParam.to ? getParam.to : this.props.dispensingData.to,
            dataFrom: getParam.from ? getParam.from : this.props.dispensingData.from,
            dataType: getParam.type ? getParam.type : this.props.dispensingData.type,
            year: year,
            timeSpan: getParam.period ? getParam.period : "monthly",
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use getDerivedStateFromProps method which will get triggered when props update. This function expects a state to be returned. So instead of setState, you will need to return the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 const getParam = this.getParamsValue();
    const year = getParam.year ? getParam.year : 2020;
      if (nextProps.dispensingData.loading) {   <-- this is comming from redux state.
       this.setState({
       selectTab: getParam.tab ? parseInt(getParam.tab) : 0,
       dataTo: getParam.to ? getParam.to : nextProps.dispensingData.to,
       dataFrom: getParam.from ? getParam.from : nextProps.dispensingData.from,
       dataType: getParam.type ? getParam.type : nextProps.dispensingData.type,
       year: year,
       timeSpan: getParam.period ? getParam.period : "monthly",
    });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use getDerivedStateFromProps method which will get triggered when props update. This function expects a state to be returned. So instead of setState, you will need to return the state.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state){
   if(props.dispensingData.loading){
     return {
       ...state,
       selectTab: getParam.tab ? parseInt(getParam.tab) : 0,
       dataTo: getParam.to ? getParam.to : nextProps.dispensingData.to,
      dataFrom: getParam.from ? getParam.from : nextProps.dispensingData.from,
      dataType: getParam.type ? getParam.type : nextProps.dispensingData.type,
      year: year,
      timeSpan: getParam.period ? getParam.period : "monthly",
     }
   }
   else{
      return state;
   } 
}
```

However it is not a recommended way. You can compute the above values in render method instead of setting the state. as render will get triggered when props change. That way you can avoid setting the unnecessary state which will trigger the render method again.